# splitting an sbrk into 2

Tags: c, malloc, sbrk, brk

To recode the malloc function, I do a `sbrk(stack)` where :

```
void *malloc(size_t size)
{
  stack = 0;
  while (stack < size)
    stack += 4096;
}
```

I malloc always more than I need then I want to take some of this allocated area of size `size` and return it, and if I want to do another malloc after I already have allocated memory so I dont have to do multiple call of sbrk.
How can i do that, i tried to go back with `brk(start_of_the_allocated_space)` , `sbrk(size)` to have the start and end of the space i need but it segfault.

EDIT:

```
struct s_block {
size_t size;
struct s_block *next;
struct s_block *prev;
void *start;
void *end;
}
```

Here is my structure.
Then I have a func who create a block

```
struct s_block   *create_block(size_t size, unsigned int stack)
{
struct s_block *block;
block = sbrk(sizeof(s_block));
block->start = sbrk(stack);
block->size = stack;
block->end = sbrk(0);
block->next = set_free_space(size, block);
block->size -= size;
block->next->prev = block;
block->prev = NULL;
return (block->next);
}

struct s_block *set_free_space(size_t size, struct s_block *block)
{ 
struct s_block new_block;
new_block = sbrk(sizeof(s_block));
new_block->start = block->start;
new_block->next = NULL;
new_block->size = size;
new_block->end = ???; // this is where I want to split the first sbrk
// I tried new_block->end = new_block->start + size; but it doesn't work either
block->start = new_block->end + 1; // and i set the new start of the big block at the end of the one i use
return (new_block);
}
```

Comment: If you `#include <stdlib.h`, the name `malloc` is reserved and must not be used by user code. Use a different name.

Comment: `stdlib.h` is of course not included

Comment: Because i include it nowhere in my program.

Comment: 1) Correct capitatilsation makes reading posts easier. It is "I", not "i". Wrong orthography is not cool. Similar for using markdown 2) **You** did not include it - sure not even indirectly? And sure it is not linked? See [ask], provide a [mcve] and all relevant information.

Comment: this code segment has no heads or tails, can you please show the full function? We cannot answer a question if we don't know what you are asking.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question, It seems you want to do one big `sbrk()` and then split a new piece everytime you malloc.

The idea is good due to the load sbrk takes on your program, but it seems you misunderstand something conscerning malloc.

Malloc in its simplest implementation allocates a certain amount of space looking like this:

```
struct metadata
{
   size_t size;
   int free;
   struct metadata *next;
   void *data; 
}
```

data being a pointer to the second part of the allocated zone, containing the actual space.
next is the pointer to the end of the allocated zone.

When you `malloc` a certain space, you create this struct and return the data pointer.
Then, to free you just have to return set the "free" value to 1.

This generates a linked list containing all your data, and all in your sbrk'd zone.

for more info on different malloc implementations, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41151828/5036612)
which uses mmap but can just as well use sbrk

Comment: "data being a pointer to the second part of the allocated zone". That's what I don't understand how you can find the pointer of the second zone. If I want to to a `malloc(10)` I'll do a `sbrk(4096)` from 0x0000 to 0x4096 for exemple, and I want to take some of this allocated space for my malloc for exemple 0x0000 to 0x0010 so my free space will be 0x0011 to 0x4096 after the malloc

Comment: If the allocated space is 10, then the next zone starts at base + 10, no?

Comment: In this case, if I have a `size_t size = 10` and a `void *data = 0x0000` (start of my `sbrk(4096)` ) doing `void *new_end = data + size` doesn't work and I can't find out why

Comment: That is probably due to the pointer type: a void* cannot be used in arithmetics since its size is unknown

Comment: How cant I set the my new_end at start + size I want to malloc then?